# Is super(props) in React Native really deprecated or just a Vs code warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, deprecation-warning

I got this warning in vs code for deprecation of super(props) but I nothing useful found in the link that mention in warning message.

warning:

```
'(props: any, context?: any): Component<any, any, any>' is deprecated
@deprecated
@see — https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html
```

constructor in my component class:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
}
```

Comment: It's not deprecated. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40511) regarding this. A quick way around to remove warning is not to pass `props` to `super`. i.e  just use `super()`.

Comment: So removing props does not affect their transfer between components?

Comment: Only caveat of removing props is you can't use `this.props` inside constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
}
```